# $_GET . Undefined Variable. Cant find solution

Tags: php, get, url-parameters

I'm having an issue and am out of ideas.

I'm trying to get a parameter from the URL, but PHP insists in saying that the variable is not defined.

The URL is

```
http://localhost/trendwatcher/index.php?date=2014-10-18
```

And the script is something like

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>

        <section id="stats">
            Showing trends for <?php echo $GET_["date"];  ?>
        </section>
```

And finally, the error:

```
Showing trends for 
Notice: Undefined variable: GET_ in C:\xampp\htdocs\trendwatcher\index.php on line 4
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It's `$_GET` not `$GET_`

Comment: Oh man, such a stupid mistake! :( Thanks and sorry for the dumb question, I don't really have a PHP programmer to exchange with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your code from:

```
<section id="stats">
     Showing trends for <?php echo $GET_["date"];  ?>
</section>
```

to

```
<section id="stats">
     Showing trends for <?php echo $_GET["date"];  ?>
</section>
```